# Custom music discs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you create custom music discs for Minecraft 1.12?

I'm trying to create new music discs, not modify existing ones.

I know about the Custom Music Discs mod, but it's for 1.10, not 1.12.2.

I'm OK with installing mods, as long as they are compatible with Forge 1.12.2

Comment: @Fabian I did search google, I couldn't find anything, and I'm trying to create new discs, not modify the other ones

Comment: @Fabian Are you implying that you can create new discs with a resource pack?

Comment: Oh, ok. No, that's impossible without mods.

Comment: @Fabian I don't mind installing mods

Comment: Oh, so you're asking for a software recommendation? That's offtopic here. You could ask on softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but they would probably also just tell you to use Google.

Comment: Actually, I'd say that this question is on-topic; it's a "how do you do X" question, which is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create new items, like music disks. That requires modifying the game.

Comment: I don't mind installing mods

Comment: I think now in 1.14 with `CustomModelData` and a resource pack you can do it now, but I'm not 100% sure. If someone could explain how in an answer that would be a good updated answer to this question.

Comment: @Nik3141 That would just change how they look.

Comment: I could've sworn I saw a video showing how to do that, so I'll keep looking, but you may be right.